# Is it possible to make GUI applications using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, user-interface

I'm trying to understand this concept: is that possible to make an application, with a graphical user interface, using JavaScript. I found that [adobe bracket](https://github.com/adobe/brackets) is also made using JavaScript, but how is its GUI designed?

Please tell me; I'm trying to make my new IDE using JavaScript. So is that possible to design GUI user interfaces using JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out node-webkit. Its for building GUI applications using javascript.

Comment: Should i need to learn first `node.js`?

Comment: yes and require.js is also needed.